# Cannot find input box in iframe or panel

Tags: excel, vb.net, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web page and can click on the side links to get to the page that I need to send a value to, but I cannot find the input box element in the iFrame or panel or whatever it is on/in. I will include a pic and some HTML for information.

This gets me to the page that i need to send a value to:

```
Selenium.FindElementById("ROOT/Incident Management", timeOut:=10000).Click
Selenium.FindElementById("ROOT/Incident Management/Search Incidents", timeOut:=10000).Click
```

I have tried switching frames but I cannot see what part of the layout that textbox is part of. I need the FIND below to find the textbox "Incident ID":

```
Selenium.FindElementById("X11", timeOut:=2000).SendKeys "IM12345"
```

HTML

```
<div class="innerNotebookPage"><div id="X9" class="SubFormat" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0.0%; width:100.0%; height:832px; overflow: visible;"><span id="X10" type="label" class="Label" style="position:absolute; top:15px; left:0.0%; width:22.3%; height:22px; height:22px; text-align:right;"><label id="X11_Label" for="X11">Incident ID</label></span><div id="X11Border" myattrib="EditBorder" style="
    display:inline;float: left; width: 100%;
    position:absolute; top:15px; left:22.3%; width:23.5%; height:22px;" class="Text"><div id="X11Edit" class="mandatoryFieldStyle xEdit" style="height:20px;"><input type="text" id="X11" name="instance/number" dvdvar="" buttonid="" datatype="string" sctype="Text" tabindex="" style="height:18px;margin-top:1px;" maxlength="" onkeyup="
              handleOnChange(this, event);
            " onfocus="handleOnFocus(this, event);" onblur="handleOnBlur(this, event); applyToSameControl(this);" onclick="handleOnClick(this, event);" onchange="handleOnChange(this, event);" value="" scripttype="text"></div></div><span id="X12" type="label" class="Label" style="position:absolute; top:15px; left:45.800000000000004%; width:22.3%; height:22px; height:22px; color: #000000 ; text-align:right;"><label id="X13_Label" for="X13">Assignment Group</label></span><input type="hidden" id="X13Hidden" value=""><div id="X13Border" class="ComFill oneButton" style="
        top:15px;
        left:68.2%;
        width:23.5%;
        height:22px;

      "><div id="X13Edit" class="mandatoryFieldStyle xEdit file_probsummary field_assignment" style="height:20px;"><div class="xEditOutter" style="
            margin-right:22px;
          "><div class="xEditInner "><input type="text" id="X13" idfill="9" for="X13" dvdvar="" scripttype="comfill" tabindex="" buttonid="comfill1425328324649" datachangeevent="" value="" flag="005" name="instance/assignment" style="height:18px;margin-top:1px" autocomplete="off" scautocomplete="1" maxlength="" onfocus="hpsm.widgets.Combo.handleOnFocus(this, event);" onblur="hpsm.widgets.Combo.handleOnBlur(this, event);" onclick="handleOnClick(this, event);" onchange="" onkeydown="" onkeyup="
    lockFormOnValueChange(this);
```

Comment: Couldn't find out how to include the picture of the page and my HTML looks fine in the draft but when I submit it seems to chop most of it off...

Comment: It will show like that only, upload it fully so will get the clear picture

Comment: Take a few minutes to fix the HTML you posted. It's not valid and is not properly indented which makes it really hard to read.